# Display GridView inside android fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, gridview

CustomGrid is my GridView adapter and MainGrid is the fragment in which I want to display the GridView. I've done this but it is not working. What should I do?

```
@Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                                 Bundle savedInstanceState) {

            View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.main_xml, container, false);

            CustomGrid adapter = new CustomGrid(MainGrid.this, web, imageId);

            GridView grid = (GridView) view.findViewById(R.id.grid);
            grid.setAdapter(adapter);

            toolbar = (Toolbar)view.findViewById(R.id.fab_toolbar);

            setupToolbar();

            return view;
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are doing wrong is, you are sending the context of fragment to adapter which is wrong. Try this

```
Activity act;
```

In `onCreateView`

```
act = getActivity();
```

And then

```
CustomGrid adapter = new CustomGrid(act, web, imageId);
```

Hope this helps